# USING a Windows 7 Restore Point

Tags: windows-7, restore

What I seek is advice, or experience of, actually USING a Windows 7 Restore Point in ANGER.

I have created the restore points, can see them, and read the instructions.  I also realize it won't harm my documents, but are there any pit-falls?

Actually the machine is a quiet, under-used with no recent program additions, so I don't anticipate any complications, nevertheless gotchas and tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about using a restore point in "anger" but I've done so in "desperation."

I've installed device drivers that completely failed and broke stuff, and uninstalling them didn't seem to help. So I used System Restore to restore my computer to the state before I installed the drivers. It worked. All three times on two different Windows 7 computers.

Keep in mind that if your system restore doesn't work, you can always undo the undo, so to speak. Or roll back to an earlier time. It is a pretty flexible system.

Just make sure to create a restore point *before* installing stuff. A lot of installers do force a restore point to be created during the installation process, but some don't.

Regarding the safety of your documents, my understanding is that System Restore uses the Volume Shadow copy Service to back up system files only, so your documents shouldn't be affected. I've had no problems.

Comment: If you are *really* concerned, you could always make a backup first before trying the System Restore. I didn't, but I do have daily backups using Rebit, and monthly backups using Paragon Backup (free edition). Yes, I am paranoid about my data, but my computer has been struck by the KSOD *three* times! You are making backups, aren't you? ;)